# How to change the input directory of streaming query at runtime?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using `spark.readStream().text(<dir>)` to run a streaming job. Is it possible to dynamically change the input directory based on current date?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the default data source for text. You'd have to create your own data source to handle this requirement.

---

What you could do instead is to read the parent directory (of the date-based directories) and simply filter by `current_date` standard function. The stream engine should filter out all the unnecessary directories and left you with the one for the current date.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with custom data source. Is there any tutorial/doc I can follow?

Comment: Please review the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/interfaces.scala).